# Xcode keyboard shortcut for intrinsic size

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder, xcode5

What is the shortcut in **XCode interface builder** to put an item back to its intrinsic size?

I saw this on a WWDC13 video, but I cannot remember or find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>=</kbd> | Cmd and equals

Comment: Leaving question as this is useful